# Copy a struct to a specific memory location in Rust

Tags: rust, unsafe, low-level, memmove, raw-pointer

If I have a `struct`, for example:

```rs
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
#[repr(C, packed)]
pub struct SomeData {
    a: u16,
    b: u64,
    c: u32,
    d: u16,
}
```

How do I copy it to a specific location in memory, e.g. to a point `0x1000` in memory efficiently? Would something like this work?

```rs
let dst_addr: u64 = 0x1000;
let src = SomeData {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
unsafe {
    let tmp: &[u8; 10] = transmute(src);
    copy(dst_addr as *mut _, tmp);
}
```

*Please note that the `repr(C, packed)` part is actually needed here.*

The software is running on bare x86_64, **ring 0**, without operating system or other limitations. Also, I'm programming **without the standard library**, so this should be achievable with only the `core` library.

This is, of course, unsafe, but it is not a problem.

**Edit**: Just clarifying: I'm copying to uninitialized memory.

Comment: There are a handful of great tutorials about writing your own kernel including [*Writing an OS in Rust in tiny steps* by Julia Evans](http://jvns.ca/blog/2014/03/12/the-rust-os-story/) and [*Writing an OS in Rust* by Philipp Oppermann](http://os.phil-opp.com/) and at least two larger projects:  [Intermezzos](https://intermezzos.github.io/book/) and [Redox](https://github.com/redox-os/redox).

Comment: @Shepmaster Yep, I have read both. I was just wondering what is the "proper" way to do this, as tutorials don't always get it right, and if there was  some great "tricks" I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I think those tutorials get read over thoroughly by the community when they are posted to the subreddit or user's forum, or even Hacker News. I'd expect them to be pretty well reviewed.

Comment: As a pedantic point, I think `usize` might be slightly better than u64 if it's to hold a pointer. On the other hand it looks like you're doing something very specific to one system!

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Yep, it's actually converted from usize, just because the pointer is actually used after this for things where it must be exactly 64bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to have a look at the [`core::ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/) module.

Its [`write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/fn.write.html) function does exactly what you wish:

> ```
> pub unsafe fn write<T>(dst: *mut T, src: T)
> ```

```
core::ptr::write(dst_addr as *mut_, src);
```

As noted, it does not drop the value current at `dst_addr` (you can use `read` to do so).

I advise against using [`intrinsics::copy_nonoverlapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/intrinsics/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html) as intrinsics will never be stabilized.

Comment: It worked => accepted! Had to use `ptr::write(dst_addr as *mut SomeData, *self);` because I was doing this inside a `SomeData`s method.